# Windows 10 Drag-and-Drop

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-10

I have a Visual Studio 2013-sp5 application which functions perfectly in Windows 7/8/8.1, including the "drag-and-drop" function from Windows Explorer into application form´s area - the user can drag files into the application.

The application is a VB.NET WIndows Desktop app. It´s is NOT neither a WPF nor an Universal Application, so, I don´t require any special function to provide compatibility from Explorer and it.

Some of my users of the newest Windows 10 are reporting the "drag-and-drop" function is not working. They drag files into the specific area and nothing happens! Neither the "drop" procedures nor any error message.

The behavior is compatible with "drag-and-drop" problem when the application is in ADMIN mode (a well-known restriction), but it is NOT (I checked by myself) in no one user.

Does anyone knows how to make my application ALSO functions in Windows 10 to this particular issue?  Again: it´s functioning perfectly in other Windows versions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved!

Windows had set the application as ADMINISTRATOR in three different places!
I went to APPLICATION PROPERTIES (right button  over its icon) and:

1) At the COMPATIBILITY tag: I had checked there and the related box was unmarked ("Execute as Administrator").  I had also checked the "All USers Settings" there and, also, the related box was unmarked too.

2) SHORTCUT - ADVANCED BUTTON: **Wow! There was the problem!** Even both above controls being unchecked, the Advanced button showed me a box (Administrator) checked!

Why Microsoft had decided to put "Run as Administrator" in 3 (three!!!) different places and why aren´t they linked?  Even two of them unmarked, that last one (Shortcut - Advanced Button) was marked...

Once unmarked, the "DnD" functions perfectly.

Comment: I just want to mark one thing for searchers like me, if you open vs with administrator rights, it won't work. If open it, as usual, it worked. Thanks for the info mate.

Comment: Same issue. But don't work for me. Running VS2017 without Admin rights or role. Create just a simple Windows Forms application with a single form. And activate AllowDrag. Event "DragDrop" is not raised in anyway. Is the some other Question at Stackoverflow with that issue?

Comment: @MarcusDock did you set all controls as above mentioned? Did you set the embedded control to allow drag/drop operations (Properties)?

Comment: See also if in your Manifest you had set your application to run as Administrator. If so, change it from "Highest Level" or "Admin" to the default behaviour.